# How can I change the location of a page and not redirect the user?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, location-href

I want to be able to change the address of a page but not issue any HTTP requests upon making that change.  How can this be done using JavaScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean like, I'm visiting `http://www.fakebank.example` and you want the address bar to display `http://www.yourbank.example`? I think there are obvious reasons this won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can set location.hash without a page load, but i'm not sure if that's what you're wanting -- your question is fairly vague.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean the address indicated in the browser's address bar, I don't believe that it can. Setting document.location or window.location will automatically trigger a page reload, as far as I know.

As olliej said, you can change the hash parameter (a.k.a. fragment identifier), which does not trigger a page reload.

Comment: This may provide some more information: <http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070710175617AAEJX2C>

Answer (score 0):

Do you not want to add a history entry? Just use `location.replace(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: it's impossible. You're asking how can you go to a different page without going to a different page, which is nonsense.

Although if a page is already in the browser cache (and a far future date has been set) then technically the user may be able to go to that page without requesting it again from your server. But you can't guarantee anything.

I think what you may be looking for is something like using frames. On `example.com/index.html` you can set up a full size frame and include a different page such as `example.com/page2.html`. Then any links within the frame won't change the URL listed in the browser. See [this tutorial](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/frames/frames_famsupp_5.html) for info.

Comment: Not exactly.  I am asking how to make the DOM believe it is at one location when it is not really at that location at all.  I don't want the page to go anywhere.

Comment: I don't get it, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is called [URL spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack#URL_spoofing_and_phishing).

[Any browser allowing this](http://www.google.com/search?q=url+spoof+ie) has a severe security issue.